# Use '1,2,3,4,5'.Contains(ID int) in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a registration column of integer list with possible values 10,2,3 or 10 or 2,3 . I have another project column ProjectID with possible values 1..10. So I am using linq to check which user in registration context should have access to project by ID.

So I am using `.Contains`

I have tried to Cast EmployeeID to string and w.ProjectID, please I am stuck as I am missing something.

```
var UserID = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]);
var listofProjects = (
                       from r in _context.Registration
                       from project in _context.ProjectMaster.Where(w => r.EmployeeID.Contains(w.ProjectID.ToString()) && r.RegistrationID == UserID)        
                       select project 
                     ).ToList();
```

My EmployeeID in Registration table is 10, and my ProjectID in project context is 10, So I have 10.Contains(10), it is counting 1, and 10 instead of 10 only.

Comment: Why you are trying `Contains` have you tried with `Equals` as you need to check exact string. Correct me if I missed something. Update your question with minimal reproducible example

Comment: I am using contains because of the nature of values in the Registration.EmployeeID. The values are integers separated by comma(,). 1 should be read distinctly from 10. 10 is a number so should  not be 1 and 10. Using 10 `Equals` 10 is fine, what about when the other part is 10, 8, 1

Comment: Perhaps this is a design issue. Why do you have your numbers in a comma separated string? Consider normalizing your tables for better accuracy.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by 
1. Convert the column with comma separated values as list

```
 var employeeView = (
                   from r in _context.Registration
                      .Where(w =>  w.RegistrationID == UserID)        
                    select r.EmployeeID 
).ToList();
```

2. Converted the list to an Array

```
                    string combindedString = string.Join(",", employeeView.ToArray());
```

3. Used the result of 2 in `Contains` as below

```
                    var listofProjects = (from project in _context.ProjectMaster
                                         where project.ProjectID.ToString().Contains(combindedString)
                                         select project).ToList();
```